# How to multiply and group using laravel eloquent with relation

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'd like to export data from my database but have problems with multiplying and sum using laravel eloquent with relation

So i have 2 tables there (budgets, items)

**Budget's:**

```
// Table
+----+---------------+-----------------+------+-----+--------------------+
| id | delivery_plan | item_code       | curr | qty | price              |
+----+---------------+-----------------+------+-----+--------------------+
|  1 | 2022-08       | 201.0001        | IDR  |   1 |    2000.0000000000 |
|  2 | 2022-08       | 201.0001        | IDR  |   3 |    2000.0000000000 |
|  3 | 2022-07       | 201.9999        | IDR  |   2 |    2000.0000000000 |
+----+---------------+-----------------+------+-----+--------------------+

// Relation

public function item()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Item::class, 'item_code', 'item_code');
}
```

**Items :**

```
// Table
+----+----------------+-----------+
| id | subgroup       | item_code |
+----+----------------+-----------+
|  1 | KOMPONEN MESIN | 201.0001  |
|  2 | EQUIPMENT LAIN | 201.9999  |
+----+----------------+-----------+

// Relation
public function budgets()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Budget::class, 'item_code', 'item_code');
}
```

So, the scenario is :

1. Multiply the "qty" * "price" columns and name them as "total" like so
2. Group them by "subgroup" column, which came from item() relationship
3. Group them by "delivery_plan"

I prefer using eloquent because to minimize the complexity because i need that "whereHas" method
This is what i've tried so far and isn't working :

```
$budgets = Budget::with('item', 'rate')->whereHas('period.term', function (Builder $builder) {
    $builder->where('name', '=', Session::get('term-budget'));
})->where('section', Session::get('section-budget'))->getQuery();

$result = $budgets->sum('price * qty')->get();
```

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by a join with SUM(), something like below (untested):

```
Budget::leftJoin('items', 'budgets.item_code', '=', 'items.item_code')
    ->addSelect('subgroup')
    ->addSelect('delivery_plan')
    ->addselect(\DB::raw('SUM(qty * price) as total'))
    ->groupBy('subgroup', 'delivery_plan')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Hello @Vadim Sirbu , this seems to be work, however as i mentioned in the question, how about the whereHas method in query like above ? As far as i know the query doesn't have the whereHas method

Comment: How about `->whereRelation('period.term', 'name', '=', Session::get('term-budget'));` ?

Comment: Cool @Vadim Sirbu this is what i was looking for, thanks for your answer, you saved my job !